# Custom iterator wrapping another iterator: iterating past the underlying end iterator without checking?

Tags: c++, iterator

I implemented an iterator wrapping class which moves an underlying `random_access_iterator` around by a certain amount/stride `S` for every step it takes.

```
Wrapper<Iterator> + i === Iterator + i*S
```

It ensembles some Kind of "every N<sup>th</sup> element iterator".

The basic idea is to iterate over columns or the diagonal of a contiguously stored matrix:

```
/*
    0  1  2
    3  4  5
    6  7  8
*/
```

With S being 4 we can iterate the diagonals using `Wrapper` `[Wrapper::begin]=0 -> 4 -> 8 -> 12=[Wrapper::end]` or the second column with `S=3` `[Wrapper::begin]=1 -> 4 -> 7 -> 10=[Wrapper::end]`
It pretty much works with the problem being the `end` iterator. The resulting `end()` iterator is probably `> last+1` (UB?).

This will fail if checked iterators are used with `Wrapper` since they will detect the last step to be out of the valid range `[begin,end]` of the underlying iterated range.

Is there any sane, performant way to get around this, other than making the `Wrapper` itself some kind of checked iterator i.e. containg a reference to the valid `end`:

```
Wrapper<Iterator> & operator++ ()
{ 
  m_it += std::min(S, std::distance(m_it, m_end));
  return *this;
}
```

versus

```
Wrapper<Iterator> & operator++ ()
{ 
  m_it += S;
  return *this;
}
```

?

Comment: FYI: here is [the first part](http://ericniebler.com/2014/02/16/delimited-ranges/) of an interesting serie of blog articles by Eric Niebler (from Boost fame) ponders the issues of the current design of iterators, their limitations, and improvements that could be made. In the course of his demonstrations, you'll find interesting strategies to build iterators for "atypic" ranges (filtered ranges, infinite ranges, ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've pretty much found the solution; because of the poor design of the STL iterators, the iterator you want needs to contain both a current and end iterator.

If the only application is iterating over a contiguously stored matrix, and the iterators are themselves bound to the matrix (e.g. a column iterator), and the matrices aren't too big, you may be able to simply ensure that there's an additional row in the underlying contiguous memory, e.g. for a 4x4 matrix, allocate 20 entries.

Comment: I had an apprehension about this :/

Comment: @Pixelchemist You're not the first.  I've used both solutions at different times.  `boost::filter_iterator` uses the first (which is the only one which will work for arbitrary filtering).  And I'm sure many others have faced the problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

The approach to jump to the *real* `end` of the underlying structure instead of iterating past it, has the downside of requiring additional diagnostics to be able to work `bidirectional` or in a `random access` fashion.

Take the question's `operator++`:

```
Wrapper<Iterator> & operator++ ()
{ 
  m_it += std::min(S, std::distance(m_it, m_end));
  return *this;
}
```

For the example matrix this iterates the second column with `S=3` using `operator++`

[Wrapper::begin] = 1 -> 4 -> 7 -> 9 = [Wrapper::end == *real* `end`]

Now one needs to know how to get back through the actual column if `operator-` or `operator--` or `operator[]` etc. are used since `9-7 != S`.

Instead of including the '*real*' `end` iterator which requires additional information to be able to walk 'bidirectional' (or in a random access fashion), the `Wrapper` iterator could increase an offset `O` instead of the underlying iterator itself and only advance the iterator upon dereferencing.

```
template<class BaseIterator,
  typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<
      typename BaseIterator::iterator_category, 
      std::random_access_iterator_tag
    >::value
  >::type * = 0>
class RASItWrapper 
  : public std::iterator_traits<BaseIterator>
{
  BaseIterator m_it;
  difference_type S, O;
public:
  // ...
  RASItWrapper & operator++ ()
  { // increment then return
    O += S;
    return *this;
  }
  // ...
  reference operator* () const { return *(m_it + O); }
  pointer   operator->() const { return (m_it + O).operator->(); }
  reference operator[] (difference_type const & i) const
  {
    return (m_it + O)[i*N];
  }
  // ...
  bool operator== (RASItWrapper const &rhs) const 
  { // perhaps only compare O since comparing different ranges is meaningless
    return m_it == rhs.m_it && O == rhs.O; 
  }
  // ...
};
```